# PHP contact forum - After clicking "send" button how to make it not change the url?

Tags: php, email, url, contact-form

I have a forum and its one part of the page and it works fine but when clicking on the send button the url always changes to my .php file so : (mysite.com/forum.php)
is there away to stop this? and have it send the infomation to the email and thats it without changing the url? I would like to keep the page the forum is in a .html because the forum just one of many things on the page.

Here are my forum and php code so far: (Its basic)

```
 <form method="post" action="forum.php">
          <div class="field name-box">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Who Are You?"/>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <span class="ss-icon">&#10004;</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field email-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@email.com"/>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <span class="ss-icon">&#10004;</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field msg-box">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Your message goes here..."/></textarea>
                <label for="msg">Msg</label>
                <span class="ss-icon">&#10004;</span>
          </div>

          <input id="submit" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

The php:

```
<?php

       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];
       $from = 'From: Datcroft Website';
       $to = 'MyEmail@hotmail.co.uk';
       $subject = 'Datcroft Site Message';

       $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n";

       if ($_POST['submit']) {
           if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {

           } else {

           }
       }
    ?>
```

Any pointers or help? I am a really noob in Php and also Ajax (Im guessing Ajax will be a solution to come up in the answers)

Thank you in advanced!

Could this work as is? from fbo3264 below in answers.

```
var Name = $("#Name").text();
var Email = $("#Email").text();
var Message = $("#Message").text();

$(document).ready(function() {


        $('#Forum1').submit(function(ev) {

            ev.preventDefault();


            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");


            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', //we use POST to submit the form
                url         : forum.php, // the url where we want to POST
                 data:{

          Name:Name,
          Email:Email,
      Message:Message

      },
                success:function(response) 
                {
                  //handle success (show a success modal or someting)
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                  //handle error
                }
            });


        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use jQuery and ajax as you've guessed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                // manually submit the form
                $('#Forum1').submit(function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    var params = {"email": $("#Email").val(), "name": $("#Name").val(),
                        "message": $("#Message").val(), "submit": true};

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST', //we use POST to submit the form
                        url: 'forum.php', // the url where we want to POST
                        data: params,
                        success: function (response)
                        {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            //handle error
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: What i forgot to mention.. If you're using this code with `$(this).serializeArray();` and don't want to change your server side code, you have to manually add the parameter for the submit button since it's not included. Something like `postData.push({name: 'submit', value: 'someVal'});` should work. Or you could just use a hidden input field inside your form like `<input type="hidden" name="submit">`.

Comment: I've update the question would the bottom code of my question work? +1'd answer, also what would I have to edit in the php file? (Really sorry 1st time I've tried to make a forum).

Comment: I've edited my code, this should work as soon as you add `id="Forum1"` to your form. You don't need to change your server side code since the parameters have the same names.

Comment: Hmm looks perfect but for some reason doesn't seem to be posting anything - atleast im getting no emails

Comment: Am i right in assuming I wont need method="post" action="forum.php" in the forum tag anymore? also the forums id is Forum1 :)

Comment: If the request is received successfully (you could check that by echoing something after `if(isset($_POST['submit']))...` which you would be your response in the ajax- success function) it could be a configuration error for the mail server in php.ini. You try using a mailer class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of the default php-mail function.
And yes, you can remove the method and action attribute ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a request to `forum.php`, the URL is going to change. You can use Apache mod_rewrite to change the URL to match the pattern you want. Some rule like this one, could do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d          
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```